# Formatting string in python to form a js function

Tags: javascript, python, string, selenium

I have a program that uses string returned from another program and ultimately generates a compound string to be used as a javascript formula in selenium javascript execution. I am having problem formatting as below-

First program returns string like `"192.235.50.33:3128"+"\n"+"192.235.50.12:3128"`
And it will be concatenated as below to form a js function-

```
'document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value="192.235.50.33:3128"+"\n"+"192.235.50.12:3128";'
```

Which will be used as a javascript code in python selenium webdriver as below-

```
browser.execute_script('document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value="192.235.50.33:3128"+"\n"+"192.235.50.12:3128";')
```

Finally my question is how to format the js code as mentioned or is there any better method to achieve this caring the context.

N.B. I am with python 2.7 and selenium (2.47.3) in windows 8.

Comment: I don't understand the question. It looks like you are just concatenating a bunch of strings together... where's the problem? What code have you tried and what was the result?

Comment: This `"192.235.50.33:3128"+"\n"+"192.235.50.12:3128"` really should be `"192.235.50.33:3128\n192.235.50.12:3128"`

Comment: In fact selenium executes js code that needs a formatting otherwise this script will not run the selenium- this formatting is 'document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value="192.235.50.33:3128"+"\n"+"192.235.50.12:3128";'

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create that executable Javascript code, you can use [str.format()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format)

```
x = "document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value="
y = "192.235.50.33:3128"
z = "192.235.50.12:3128"
string = '{}"{}"\n{};'.format(x, y, z)
```

Comment: 'document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value="' returns - "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Comment: Editted it,  try it again and print the string to make sure you're getting correct JS code

Comment: Nops, i do not want slashes either . As it returned 'document.getElementsByTagName(\'textarea\')[0].value="192.235.50.33:3128"\n192.235.50.12:3128;' Again ips anports are not formatted as i wanted.